# In using Hibernate 4, what dependency to I need for `org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider`?

Tags: java, hibernate

In using Hibernate 4, what POM dependeny do I need for `org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider` so that the lines in the configuration file will work?

```
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
                org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
            </prop>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate-ehcache contains the provider you're looking for. Add this to your dependency management file or [download the library directly](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache).

Maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>  
   <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
   <version>{hibernate-version-goes-here}</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:{hibernate-version-goes-here}"
```